# How do I run a Meteor app in Xcode with a settings.json file?

Tags: angularjs, xcode, meteor, ionic-framework

I have been following [this tutorial](http://info.meteor.com/blog/whatsapp-with-meteor-angular-and-ionic) to create a WhatsApp style messaging app with Meteor, Angular and Ionic.

It works well with settings.json when I run it on the simulator with this:

meteor run ios --settings server/settings.json

But when I try to run it on my phone through Xcode:

meteor run ios-device --settings server/settings.json

It crashes out at the moment it needs something from the settings.json

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--mobile-settings   Set optional data for the initial value of Meteor.settings
                    in your mobile application. A new value for
                    Meteor.settings can be set later by the server as part of
                    hot code push.
```

Use `--mobile-settings` when deploying to mobile to send the initial settings information for the mobile device - this gets overwritten if you declare `--settings` on the server via hot code push once the app connects but it will need the mobile settings initially to tell it what to do prior to hot code push being applied.

I've only ever used Android but I guess the same applies for iOS in that you will probably want to declare `--mobile-server http://server:port` to tell it where to connect to on your network once deployed.

You may want to consider putting your settings.json into your root folder not your server folder to ensure your entire code base has access, you can control the visibility of values in there by using private and public objects

```
{
  "randomkey": "AB231489756"
  "public": {
    "val1": "AB4444"
  },
  "private": {
    "val2": "AB5555"
  }
}
```

In the above randomkey and val2 a private and only accessible on the server whilst val1 under the public object is visible to both client and server